# How to customize fisheye menu !

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, customization, flicker, fisheye

I am not a pro in jquery and js. I have used  jqDock plugin to create fisheye menu for my web site  and with the help of a friend I managed to give the menu an active state so on different pages that specific menu element would remain expanded.

Here is the problem: If you hover your mouse in between the two elements of the menu and move slowly between them upwards or downwards , you'll get this terrible flicker effect. I don't know why it happens and how can I fix it and if it is doable at all as far as it's a plugin and I haven't write the code from scratch!

The menu example on the website that I provided the link on top doesn't have this bug. If I remove the active property the flickering will go away.

here is the url to my website:
[link to the menu](http://maryamkazerooni.com/beta/portfolio.html)

I did search the entire forum, I searched the jquery forum itself, and even posted my question but I got no answer, except one which was not helpful. Basically the questions on the forums are more about implementing the fish-eye plug in, or giving it a fixed position and ... I haven't come across and post that actually wants to manipulate the plug -in in this specific way.

I appreciate your help a looooot
cheers.
MARYAM

Here is the  little jq that I have written and we had to change the jq library that came with the pluin as well;
Let me know if I need to include more code in order to help you help me :)

```
function loadPageContent(tagid, filename, actionafter, active) {
 $.ajax({
  url: filename,
  success: function(result) {
   $('#' + tagid).html(result);
   if (actionafter == 1){
        $("#scr-menu").jqDock({
     align: 'middle',
     size: 55,
     duration:800,
     coefficient :1.5,
     fadeIn: 0,
     distance: 130,
     step:50,
       active: active
     });
   }
  },
  error: function(result) {
   $('#' + tagid).html(result);
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only help if I can see the full (ie. non-compressed) source code. The code included on the website has been modified (from jqDock v1.6 source) and re-compressed, which makes it extremely difficult (understatement!) to tell what has been changed. (I have also responded - with the same answer - to a direct email from the poster)